# Manage workspaces after changing folder structure of a TFS project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have several projects in TFS. Now I wanted to modify folder structure of the project.

Current structure is as shown below. With `my project` folder i have all the forms and .sln files.

```
Project Root
  my project
     myproject.sln
     file1.vb
     file2.vb
      .
      .
      .
     file n.vb
```

Now I want move the all the other files other than .sln file to a new folder named `codingfilesfolder` .

```
Project Root
  my project
     myproject.sln
     codingfilesfolder
       file1.vb
       file2.vb
        .
        .
        .
      file n.vb
```

So now all the files other than .sln file will be in new folder. I can do it easily in TFS by adding files. But there are so many workspaces of developers for this project. So after i do changes in structure , if anyone does get latest version then files will be messed up in there workspace and he will be again getting a new folder which I created . And also files where they have made changes will be outside the current folder of TFS and there changes cannot be checked in or recognised. So how can I manage the existing workspaces after changing the folder structure of TFS project?

Comment: Would it not be more consistent to move the solution up a directory rather than all the files down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you do a "move" on the files, and the check-in shows as a rename/move, then everything should just work.  When the other devs do a Get Latest it will move their file keeping their pending changes in tact.

What you want to avoid is TFS detecting it as a delete+add instead of a move.